# long Text shifting to left in textview in android

Tags: android, textview

I am facing strange problem with `TextView`. When the text is too long the content is shifting to the left and the only the dots are visible. Here is my layout code.

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/coinIcon"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="2dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_single_coin"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/prizeSize"
                    android:layout_width="13dp"
                    android:layout_height="13dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/circular_background"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:freezesText="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="6sp"
                    tools:text="100"
                    android:maxEms="20"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

This text fits perfect.

[image]

This removes the text:

[image]

As you can see the text is currently fitting the `TextView`. But as the text grows dots(..) are only visible. What can be the best solution to show text in that small size ?

Comment: for test case `android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"` .Remove `android:ellipsize="end"`

Comment: the  text should be shown inside the grey round background ??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya but that will make the design little ugly. The low TextView will look bigger. I want that TextView as the counter.

Comment: Yes it should be inside the circular background @Saneesh

Comment: use this library; https://github.com/steelkiwi/BadgeHolderView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=6029

Comment: @Hiren your textview is not large enough to  have given text with textsize. Please try reducing text size

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya add your comment as answer. Will upvote and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first **`INCREASE`** your respective [**`android:layout_width`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_width) & [**`android:layout_height`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_height) .

```
android:layout_width="16dp"
android:layout_height="16dp"
```

Remove [**`android:ellipsize="end"`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize) .

Answer (score 1):

Remove android:ellipsize="end" and Add SingleLine is true

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/prizeSize"
   android:layout_width="13dp"
   android:layout_height="13dp"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:background="@drawable/circular_background"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   android:freezesText="true"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
   android:maxLines="1"
   android:scrollHorizontally="true"
   android:textColor="#fff"
   android:textSize="6sp"
   tools:text="100"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:maxEms="3"/>
```

Comment: didnt work. removing `android:ellipsize="end"` worked for me.

Comment: `singleLine` is deprecated. `maxLines` is used.

Answer (score 1):

Use BadgeHolderView library..
Here is the link

https://github.com/steelkiwi/BadgeHolderView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=6029

Simply replace the code by this

```
 <com.steelkiwi.library.view.BadgeHolderLayout
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:bhl_default_badge_background="@color/color3"
        app:bhl_text_color="@android:color/white"
        app:bhl_text_size="12sp"
        app:bhl_badge_radius="10dp"
        app:bhl_text_font="Pacifico.ttf">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_drawable"/>
    </com.steelkiwi.library.view.BadgeHolderLayout>
```

Comment: Thought not to include a library for this. Anyways @IntelliJAmiya solution is worked for me.